# How to use the current date format in a SQL Query

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g

I am trying to do a query that calculates the days of past due library books in days. I also want to display the Patron's Last Name ( the person who borrowed the book), Book Title, the Due Date of the book.
I ran a simple query to understand what I am looking for. The code I ran is as follows:

```
    SELECT PATRON.PAT_LNAME, BOOK.BOOK_TITLE, CHECKOUT.CHECK_DUE_DATE, 
           CHECKOUT.CHECK_IN_DATE 
           FROM CHECKOUT, BOOK, PATRON
           WHERE CHECKOUT.BOOK_NUM=BOOK.BOOK_NUM 
           AND CHECKOUT.PAT_ID= PATRON.PAT_ID
           AND CHECK_IN_DATE IS NULL
```

I need to calculate the days that the book is overdue from the date that it was due. I want to use the current date to calculate the days that the book is overdue, although I am not sure how to do that. I know there is a SYSDATE function that gives the current date. I do not know how to use the SYSDATE function.

Comment: SYSDATE is very easy to use: you just write its name (just like that: SYSDATE) where you need it. To compute days difference, you just put a - (minus) sign between the dates; one of them may be your column name and the other can be SYSDATE. You need to decide what you want to do with the time-of-day (book due date at 10 a.m., SYSDATE is currently 2 p.m. - how do you handle the fractional days?)

Answer (score 1):

I think the marker for a past due book is that the current date is *greater* than the due date.  So you can just compare the due date against `SYSDATE` to determine which books are overdue and by how many days.

```
SELECT
    p.PAT_LNAME,
    b.BOOK_TITLE,
    c.CHECK_DUE_DATE, 
    c.CHECK_IN_DATE,
    SYSDATE - c.CHECK_DUE_DATE AS num_days_due
FROM CHECKOUT c
INNER JOIN BOOK b
    ON c.BOOK_NUM = b.BOOK_NUM
INNER JOIN PATRON p
    ON c.PAT_ID = p.PAT_ID
WHERE
    c.CHECK_IN_DATE IS NULL AND
    SYSDATE > c.CHECK_DUE_DATE;
```

In Oracle we can just subtract two dates to get the difference in days.  Note also that I replaced your implicit inner joins with explicit joins.  This is the preferred way of writing a join query.

Comment: How does that help with (quote from the original post with my emphasis): "I need to calculate **the days that the book is overdue** from the date that it was due."? Sounds like "how many days is the book overdue?"

Comment: @mathguy Your point about fractional dates is still valid.  Though I know people who used to work in a public library and I seem to recall that overdue fees were on a per diem basis.

Comment: lol - I missed the NUM_DAYS_DUE in the SELECT clause, I just saw the WHERE clause. So, never mind my first comment. Then: regarding days due and "per diem" - I believe it is also the case, though, that the patron has time till midnight at the end of the due date to return the book and be "in good standing" regardless of when they borrowed it (what time of day). Not sure how the fractional part of SYSDATE is treated for the purpose of calculating the fine... rounded down, or up?

Comment: @mathguy I have a cop-out to get around this  I can say that the library should run the above query as a batch job once per day, right after midnight.  This way, even a book which were due at 11:59pm would still be due at that point.  But I agree with your catch on fractional days.